# index_users_on_unlock_token unique validation error in rails / devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Rails 4 and devise, and am running into an issue when I try to update users from my admin console (I'm using Rails Admin). Every time I try to update, it gives me an error:

```
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_unlock_token"
```

This is occurring presumably because the unlock_token field is null for most users. But surely fields that can be null can still be indexed? The unlock_token is only set when a user is locked out of their account right?

I can easily avoid this issue by entering a random string in the confirmation token field, but this seems like a bad way to deal with it. Any better ideas?

My Users table definition (well, the relevant portion of it):

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                                               default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",                                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "screen_name"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                                       default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.integer  "failed_attempts",                                     default: 0
    t.string   "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
end
```

The error from my logs:

```
  SQL (10.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "unlock_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 7  [["unlock_token", ""], ["updated_at", Mon, 24 Feb 2014 02:59:58 UTC +00:00]]
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_unlock_token"
DETAIL:  Key (unlock_token)=() already exists.
```

Comment: Yep, I reckon the unlock_token is only set when a user wants to unlock their account and multiple NULL values should be allowed for a unique index.  Can you confirm the db/version (looks like postgresql).  Could you show the table definition from the db?  Also, development.log messages for when you update a user?

Comment: Thanks tim, I've posted the table info above. The dev log gives the same error as I mentioned above, just saying the key (null) already exists - do you need the full trace? psql --version gives me 9.1.3. Strange thing is - when I log in as that user and update their details, it works fine. Only fails when I'm logged in as an admin (to rails admin), updating another user's account

Comment: why would you need such an index on that column? another thing, `NULL` is ignored "However, two null values are not considered equal in this comparison."

Comment: the index is added automatically by devise, so I'm assuming its there for a reason

Comment: Yes, indexed for fast lookup, unique because an unlock key must be specific to a user.  Info from dev log would be good to confirm parameters being passed to action, SQL being executed etc.  For example, the message above says nothing about NULL, just that unique index was violated, so what if, for example, the value is actually being set to an empty string, not NULL, and another row already has an empty string?  Your comment about it being admin edits only also makes me suspect something like this that is behaving differently from a normal user updating themselves.

Comment: Ok I've posted the exact error above - does this help?

Comment: I think it helps enough. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments, judging by the error message from the logs it looks like the value is indeed being set to an empty string instead of nil/NULL (`["unlock_token", ""]`).  I've never used rails_admin, but is it showing you a form with all user fields on it by default and you just leave the `unlock_token` blank (which causes the problem, so you enter a random string instead)?  You need to change this so that either you don't touch the attribute at all (i.e. can you tell rails_admin to avoid attributes? - I can't see why you'd ever want to manually edit an unlock token column) or find a way to tell rails_admin that it should convert an empty string to nil for that attribute.  Alternatively, you could ensure blank strings are changed to nil for `unlock_token` (and perhaps other attributes too - e.g. the other tokens).  Alternatively, you could use something like the nilify_blanks gem to do this.

It's rather strange that only the `unlock_token` is being updated (apart from `updated_at` of course), but without more context from the log (i.e. from the point the parameters hit the action until the end of view rendering) it's difficult to tell why that's happening.

Comment: You got it - I changed the field to not display at all in the rails admin config, and it now works fine - thanks!

Comment: Just a quick link for docs on removing fields: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#exclusion

Comment: For the record, this also helped me with this same error for `reset_password_token` in Administrate as well. So thanks for this!